# Send email in HTA using JavaScript and hide the sender's email address

Tags: javascript, html-email, outlook-2003, hta, activexobject

I'm using an HTA at work with many options, now I'm trying to add a page that allows you to send an email directly from the HTA without opening MS Outlook.

I'm using Outlook 2003. I tried two ways to create the email sending page:

**1. Using Outlook.Application ActiveX Object -** It didn't work because its seems to work only with Outlook 2007, So meanwhile I left it out of the question.

**2. Using simple HTML with 'mailto:' -** It is working fine to send simple Emails, but I have a problem that I'm not able to solve.

In Outlook I can send emails from a 'fake' address called '*Service Mail*' ( I just write it in the 'From' field ) so customers won't be able to reply to my emails. I want to do it also in my HTA page, but I think this option doesn't exist.

Is there any way doing it? Maybe by using an ActiveX Object for outlook 2003 and do it with that object?

***Important: I can only use client side languages, because I don't have a server.***

Thanks,
Rotem

Comment: This is inside a local network where all clients have Outlook 2003 installed, correct?

Comment: You're going to have some delivery issues if you don't specify a proper `From:` in the headers.

Comment: This would probably be a million times simpler (and more future proof) to do using a SMTP server

Answer (score 1):

I've made a HTA in VBScript that sends email. It connects directly to the mail server. You don't need Outlook (or any other email client) installed so it's pretty useful. Use something like this:

```
With CreateObject("CDO.Message")
  .Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "smtp.server.com"
  .Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing")  = 2
  .Subject  = "The subject line"
  .To       = "recipient@email.com"
  .From     = "sender@email.com"
  .TextBody = "The body of the email"
  ' or .CreateHTMLbody "page.htm"
  .AddAttachment "C:\path\to\file.txt"
  .Send
End With
```

... you get the idea.

Edit: Just saw this request was specifically for javascript, but it's essentially the same:

```
var mailobj = Server.CreateObject("CDO.Message");
mailobj.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "smtp.server.com";
mailobj.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing")  = 2;
mailobj.Subject  = "The subject line";
mailobj.To       = "recipient@email.com";
mailobj.From     = "sender@email.com";
mailobj.TextBody = "The body of the email";
mailobj.Configuration.Fields.Update();
mailobj.Send();
```

Comment: Hi, just saw it! seems great..! I should write the server address in the 2nd line quotes? I can find the server address in my outlook, right? Thanks a lot

Comment: You may need to add username/password fields: